# Linux Kali - Boot to windows

Tags: windows-8.1, kali-linux

I've burned a linux kali disc and run it with "Live amd".

Upon restarting my PC, I assumed that I can simply boot my windows again, as I know it from another linux disc.

Apparently it is unable to boot, saying that no bootable device has been found.

I have googled and checked my partitions with gparted. As it says "used 127.90 GiB" I assume that all my data is still there, but it cannot boot for some reason.

Is there any way, preferably without recovery disc as I don't have internet access on my PC at the moment....., to boot back to windows ?
Or do I need the recovery disc ?

Also, is there a proper way to simply boot from disc and get rid of kali upon shutdown/restart ?

Comment: That shouldn't have broken your windows system at all, assuming it was live booted. Did you make any other changes getting kali to boot?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek All I've done was booting it with the live option, and then do a shutdown. After that I tried to boot normally from my SSD and I got the message that no bootable device has been found. No I did nothing else. Disc, boot, let it load & start, shutdown.

Comment: You will need a windows / OEM repair disk for the following: 1) Boot off the disk 2) Look for Command Prompt 3) Enter "bootrec /fixmbr" and press enter 4) Enter "bootrec /fixboot" and press enter. 5) Restart and see if that helped.

Comment: @unseen_rider So I will need a windows disc ? I assume it can't be fixed without ?

Comment: maybe you changed the boot order? and didn't change it back?

Comment: Using a windows / OEM disc is the only legal way I know of for fixing boot problems other than changing boot order or replacing / repairing hard disk.

Answer (score 2):

Live CD-s are using RAM memory for system.
After the restart, your system should boot fine, unless you modified/removed windows boot files on your partition while in linux. In this case, you would need recovery disk.
Also, have you tried booting from your hard drive explicitly? Maybe the default boot order is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it could not do a clean shutdown for some reason. Booting and doing a shutdown multiple times let me boot back into windows. Be sure to do a shutdown on top right from the GUI & not from terminal.